# NotFoundError during fitting my CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, enotfound-error

I was training the CNN model and got this error.

```
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Rohit\Desktop\New folder(2)\2_1_train_age_model.ipynb Cell 31 line 3
      1 # Fitting the above created CNN model.
----> 3 final_cnn_history = final_cnn.fit(train_aug_dataset,
      4                                   batch_size = 33,
      5                                   validation_data=test_dataset,
      6                                   epochs=15,
      7                                   callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
      8                                   shuffle=False    
      9                                  )
     10 print("Done")

File c:\Users\Rohit\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\Rohit\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:54, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52 try:
     53   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
...
; No such process
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_test_function_29562]
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

here is the model

```
final_cnn = Sequential()
final_cnn.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='tanh', input_shape=(16, 16, 1)))    
final_cnn.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

final_cnn.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='tanh'))
final_cnn.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

final_cnn.add(Dense(64, activation='tanh'))
final_cnn.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

final_cnn.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
# Output layer with 7 nodes (equal to the no. of classes).
final_cnn.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

final_cnn.summary()
print("Done")
```

At first, I thought it was a problem with my CSV file, in which I used the directory of images and their age.
but after a few Google searches I realised it might be the problem with my tf version,

I am using cuda 11.2 and cudnn 8.1, I have tried Python version 3.10 and 3.9 with tf versions 2.10,2.7,2.8 but still, this error remains the same.

Please tell me what this error is about, is it a problem with the version or anything else?